# Johansen cointegration test for ECM model

Tags: trend, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, ecm

I'm dealing with the Johansen cointegration test before running an ECM model.

I cannot figure out which type of test execute: with/without constant, with/without trend, ...

How can I choose the correct version? Do I have to do it a priori?

And if the test tells variables are cointegrated with trend, what does it mean? Do I have to estimate an ECM with trend?

I've read some post on this topic, but no one answers my quesions.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180854/interpretation-of-results-using-johansen-and-engle-granger-2-step-cointegration?rq=1

Comment: @utobi not really... I need to understand what "trend cointegration" means and if it implies the necessity of a trend in my ECM model. And is there a method to decide a priori if I have to run the cointegration test with or without trend?